# How to keep StackExchange.Redis open while subscribed

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

My program closes even when subscribed to a channel. Is there a correct way to keep this open? (ex no `Console.ReadLine();`)

```
using System;
using StackExchange.Redis;

namespace redis.test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");
            IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();

            ISubscriber sub = redis.GetSubscriber();

            sub.Subscribe("test", (channel, message) => {
                Console.WriteLine("Got notification: " + (string)message);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ManualResetEvent`.

```
using (var exitEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false))
{
    Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, eventArgs) =>
    {
        eventArgs.Cancel = true;
        exitEvent.Set();
    };

    ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");
    IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();
    ISubscriber sub = redis.GetSubscriber();
    sub.Subscribe("test", (channel, message) => {
        Console.WriteLine("Got notification: " + (string)message);
    });

    Console.WriteLine("waiting...");
    exitEvent.WaitOne();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

answering from reddit:

Seeing this code, the current behavior of what you are describing is intended since the program is already done after that `console.writeline()`.

I'm not exactly sure what you want to do to not kill the application after the writeline. If you could say the reason why you want to suspend the application after the writeline then maybe I can help you more.

If you just want to see the output afterwards, you could pipe the output to a text file by doing

> cmd /c "C:\path\to\your\application.exe" > myfile.txt

but, `console.readline()` is an easier way to do that

Comment: I'd like to wait for future messages, so a writeline after every message sent.

Comment: I'm not sure whether redis has the ability to push notifications to you or you need to request. If the former then you'll need to check the docs for how. If the latter then you'll need to decide how often you want to check and then write suitable code to do that. This could be as simple as a `while (true)` with a `Thread.Sleep` to throttle the requests...

Comment: If you're adding more code after that, put it on a thread and put a `while(true)` or `sleep` in there.

Comment: If I add a Thread.Sleep right under the subscribe code and publish messages to the channel, they appear in the console. Multiple GitHub issues appear to show that it's possible to wait for messages without blocking the thread. I'm not against Thread.Sleep but it doesn't seem best practice. The end goal is to call a method to handle the messages as they come in.